# call firebase.initializeApp() problem on react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I've created react app using this npx react-native init --template @react-native-firebase/template MyAwesomeApp then setup the firebase everything is ok until I encountered an error:

> No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp().

Below is my code for App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const usersCollection = firestore().collection('Food');


function Addfood()  { 
  usersCollection
.add({
  color: "White",
  name: "None"
})
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Addfood/>
      <Text>Test2</Text>
    </View>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you call firebase.initializeApp() anywhere?

Comment: how to properly call it? I've tried
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
firestore.initializeApp(firestore)
but gives me other error

Comment: um do you call firebase.initializeApp() ?

Comment: you should import firebase from 'firebase/app' and then firebase.firestore()....

Comment: @youssefali how to call?

Comment: @TomSlutsky
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const usersCollection = firebase.firestore().collection('Food');
like this?

Comment: sorry ignore that. documentation says you import it right. maybe you have some configurations to do like importing google-service.json to your project